# How do I make the block pass light with the texture pack

Tags: minecraft

My question is not how to set block texture transparent. Let's say I have obsidian. I want to obsidian pass light like glass. When I build an obsidian home everywhere going to be dark. I want the outside light to come in, like on the glass block.

[image: this]

[image: to this]

I need to do this with texture pack or data pack. Can I do this?

Comment: Does this help at all? https://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding-java-edition/minecraft-mods/modification-development/2553647-changing-block-opacity or perhaps  Block#propagatesSkylightDown

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a transparent block like glass and just replace the texture with obsidian.

Obsidian:
[image: Obsidian]

Glass w/ obsidian texture:
[image: Glass w/ obsidian texture]